# Pass nested env variables to Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

Due to security concerns, I can't keep the credentials in values.yaml in the CI/CD system. I'm trying to pass the credentials directly to the helm using --set argument instead. The application requires some of its configs to be in nested formats as shown below.

https://github.com/StackStorm/stackstorm-k8s/blob/master/values.yaml#L67

https://github.com/StackStorm/stackstorm-k8s/blob/master/values.yaml#L89

I'm unable to find a better way to pass these variables to helm during install/upgrade.

```
configs:
  core.yaml: |
    ---
    name: "CoreName"
    value: "CoreValue"
   
  element1.yaml: |
    ---
    element_url: "https://example.com/element/"
    invit_invite: "var1,var2,var3"
    element_token: "elementtokenhere"
    element_labels:
      name: "value"
      type: "value"

  element2.yaml: |
    ---
    name: "name"
    type: "value"
```

Is there a better way to handle this within helm arguments before I look for options to change the chart itself?